# How to transpose the row to column in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

My Base table like below

[image]

I need output like below

[image]

can anyone help me on this

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+%5Boracle%5D+pivot+rows+columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this

```
SELECT Branch,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'deposit' THEN Count ELSE NULL END) Deposit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'transfer' THEN Count ELSE NULL END) Transfer,           
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'withdraw' THEN Count ELSE NULL END) Withdraw           
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY Branch
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate data, conditionally. Sample data in lines #1 - 11; query begins at line #12.

```
SQL> with base (type, branch, count) as
  2    (select 'deposit' , 101, 100 from dual union all
  3     select 'deposit' , 102, 150 from dual union all
  4     select 'deposit' , 103, 200 from dual union all
  5     select 'transfer', 101, 50  from dual union all
  6     select 'transfer', 102, 100 from dual union all
  7     select 'transfer', 103, 150 from dual union all
  8     select 'withdraw', 101, 25  from dual union all
  9     select 'withdraw', 102, 50  from dual union all
 10     select 'withdraw', 103, 75  from dual
 11    )
 12  select branch,
 13    sum(case when type = 'deposit'  then count end) deposit,
 14    sum(case when type = 'transfer' then count end) transfer,
 15    sum(case when type = 'withdraw' then count end) withdraw
 16  from base
 17  group by branch
 18  order by branch
 19  /

    BRANCH    DEPOSIT   TRANSFER   WITHDRAW
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101        100         50         25
       102        150        100         50
       103        200        150         75

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [pivot table](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot) is for:

```
select *
from <table>
pivot (
  sum(count)
  for type in (
    'deposit' as DEPOSIT,
    'transfer' as TRANSFER,
    'withdraw' as WITHDRAW
  )
)
```